# How to import the output of python code from jupyter notebook to php?

Tags: php, python, jupyter-notebook

I am building a recommendation system for a web page. The recommendation system is built using Python in Jupyter Notebook. I want to transfer this output to my web page (built using PHP). How can it be done so that my project works as expected?

I tried to import the CSV file to MySQL, but it failed.

Comment: You can save in file or database and create PHP code which read it. OR you can generate directly HTML and display even without PHP.

Comment: if something failde then describe it and show full error message. Maybe you made only small mistake.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is to embed the Python code in an AWS Lambda function with an API  gateway in order to create a REST API for the function.

Then you can make a POST request from your PHP page to the endpoint.

See guideline [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-getting-started-with-rest-apis.html).